# UnsatisfiledLinkerError while trying to create lotus notes session

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I was trying to create lotus notes session, to send email out. While doing so I am getting :

```
"UnsatisfiedLinkerError : lotus.domino.local.Session.NCreateSession(I)J"
```

While trying research on the error, I understood I need to add nlsxbe.dll file to the project.

If that is so, how do I add a dll to eclipse project?

If that is not the issue, please help me out to resolve this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Notes.jar` to your project and build path. You can find the file in directory `...\Notes\jvm\lib\ext`.

You get the session with

```
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.NotesThread;
import lotus.domino.Session;
...
NotesThread.sinitThread();
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();
```

Comment: Actually, I think a linker error indicates that it can't find nlsxbe.dll and/or nnotes.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Lotus Notes installed on your computer? You don't add it to your project in eclipse. Adding nlsxbe.dll would do you very little good, because nlsxbe.dll depends on nnotes.dll and various other modules. You must have a full installation of Notes and/or Domino on your machine, and the notes.ini file that is found on the system PATH must point to it. You will also have to actually run the installed Notes client at least once in order to establish the id file that your code will use for the connections that it makes.