# Retrieving user info from Lotus Notes session

Tags: lotus-notes

I am writing a eclipse/Notes plug-in, and I would like to know how can I retrieve the user info (e.g. login), from the logged user session.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/27850510/2065611 ?

Comment: It works! Thank you.